# A question on contraction morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism between varieties. $f$ is called a contraction if each fiber of $f$ is connected. Assume now that $X$ is normal. It is known that the morphism $f$ is contraction if and only if $f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$. Why is this true? How should I understand the latter condition $f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y$?

Comment: Your definition is incomplete and the iff needs some extra hypothesis. Please check first with your source.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out a mistake. I forgot normality of $X$, I guess.

Comment: Really please check with your source before.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Theorem on Formal Functions?

Comment: For the "if" part, as Matt said, take a look at Hartshorne Chapter III, Corollary 11.3. "Let $f:X \to Y$ be a projective morphism of Noetherian schemes and $f_*\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_Y.$ Then $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected for every $y \in Y.$"